# UART transmitter not transmitting values as expected

Tags: c, embedded, uart

I am writing some code for an embedded UART transmitter on the [MSP430FR5994 microcontroller](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau367p/slau367p.pdf?ts=1649150529600&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FMSP430FR5969). My plan for this UART transmitter is to eventually get it to access an int from an ADC sourcing from a varying voltage. But before I get to this point, I have run into some issues with UART transmission.

What the following code does is that I set an int as a message, configure the UART settings, and then at the switch...case operation at the bottom, the message is put through a UART transmit buffer. I am able to access the message through an RS232 terminal (I used Termite).

```
#include <msp430.h>

int message = 65;
const unsigned char messageLength = sizeof(message);

unsigned char TXbytes = 0;

int main(void)
{
    /*There was some code here about configuring other parts of the MCU. There were pin outputs, 
    clock settings, and a watchdog timer. I have removed them for your sake 
    but please let me know if you want them back.*/

    // Configure USCI_A0 for UART mode
    UCA0CTLW0 = UCSWRST;                    // Put eUSCI in reset (p788)
    UCA0CTLW0 |= UCSSEL__SMCLK;             // CLK = SMCLK

    // Baud Rate calculation for 19200
    // 8000000/(16*19200) = 26.042
    // Fractional portion = 0.042
    // User's Guide Table 21-4: UCBRSx = 0xD6
    // UCBRFx = int ( (0.042)*16) = 1
    UCA0BRW = 26;                           // 8000000/16/19200, p789
    UCA0MCTLW |= UCOS16 | UCBRF_1 | 0xD600; // UCOS16 = Oversampling enable, used when high frequency clk is used, probably divides everything by 16, UCBRF = fine turner when UCOS16 is active.

    UCA0CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                  // Initialize eUSCI
    UCA0IE |= UCRXIE;                       // Enable USCI_A0 RX interrupt

    while(1){
    __delay_cycles(200000);
    UCA0IE |= UCTXIE;                       //Flag for transmission is enabled

    __bis_SR_register(LPM3_bits | GIE);       // Enter LPM3, interrupts enabled
    __no_operation();                           // For debugger
    }
}

#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector=EUSCI_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_A0_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(EUSCI_A0_VECTOR))) USCI_A0_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
    switch(__even_in_range(UCA0IV,USCI_UART_UCTXCPTIFG))
    {
      case USCI_NONE: break;
      case USCI_UART_UCRXIFG:
          break;

      case USCI_UART_UCTXIFG:           //TXIFG = transmission flag, needs manual activation

          // Transmit the byte
          //UCA0TXBUF is taking message and sending it over.
          UCA0TXBUF = message;   //TXBUF = Transmit Buffer, p791

          // If last byte sent, disable the interrupt
          if(TXbytes == messageLength)
          {
              UCA0IE &= ~UCTXIE;
              TXbytes = 0;
          }
          __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM3_bits);
          break;

      case USCI_UART_UCSTTIFG: break;
      case USCI_UART_UCTXCPTIFG: break;
      default: break;
    }
}
```

The message I am accessing, however, is not what I expected. The message I expect to receive is "65", and instead I am receiving "A". This makes some sense given that 65 = A in ASCII, but I want the terminal to print "65", and not "A". I am unsure how to proceed.

[image]

Placing a char[] message onto UART, like below, still works.

```
char message[] = "Help!\n";
```

[image]

Please let me know if more information is needed. Or if there is something glaringly obvious that I missed.

Comment: Where do you convert the number 65 into the string "65"?

Comment: Do you want to send the *string* `"65"` rather than the integer `65`? Because if you want to send the integer, then that's what you're already is doing. It's just that the receiving terminal interprets it different from your intentions.

Comment: It's not clear how exactly you thought `UCA0TXBUF = message` would print anything but a single character. To send multiple characters, you need a loop or repeated ISR calls.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In this example, yes. Eventually, I want to print an ADC value between 0 - 400. Judging by the responses, I get the impression there is something glaringly obvious that I missed.

Comment: Either convert the data to a string, and send it character by character in a loop. *Or* configure the receiver to display the raw data instead of assuming it't text. Those are the two options you have.

Answer (score 1):

- Declare `message` as a character array.
- If some data should be printed as ASCII digits on a PC terminal, then covert each digit to the corresponding ASCII character and store it as a string in your array, optionally with CR+LF, optionally null terminated.
- In the ISR send `message[TXbytes]`. For this to work, `TXbytes` has to be actually increased each time you hit the ISR.
- Make all variables shared with the ISR as `volatile` to prevent dangerous optimizations.
- Protect all variables shared with the ISR from race conditions, so that your main program isn't writing to those variables while the ISR is running.

If this is just some quick & dirty program it might be easier to skip interrupts and just send data by busy-wait polling the tx flag.

Comment: What does it mean to "busy-wait polling"?

Comment: @HFOrangefish Something like `while(UART_FLAGREG & UART_TX_BUSY) { }` (translate register and flag names to whatever terms STM32 uses). Just stall the whole CPU waiting for transmission to finish. Not acceptable if your program has other things to do, but for some quick & dirty serial communication, it will be easier to implement.